# Align PieChart to the height of a component in row

Tags: typescript, flexbox

I have a pie chart, and on the left, the descriptions for every section. How can I make it so the `PieChart` gets aligned with the yellow line? There are multiple charts, and not every chart has their descriptions aligned in the same way as the picture (i.e. not as separated from one another on another chart due to the length of the description's text)

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
<View style={[style, { flex: 0.5, justifyContent: 'center', ...sharedStyles.row, height: '100%' }]}>
    <PieChartLayer data={evaluationValues} pieChartSize={pieChartSize} style={{ marginRight: spacings.m }} />
    <View style={{ ...sharedStyles.flex, justifyContent: 'space-around', flex: 1 }}>
          {lineDescriptions.map((description, index) => (
               <ChartSectionDescription
                  key={`${description}-${index}`}
                  color={getColor(index, descriptionsChart, PerceptionsPieChartColors)}
                  text={description}
                  leftDotOrLine='line'
                  value={evaluationValues[index].value}
                  textStyle={{ fontSize: 10 }}
               />
           ))}
     </View>
</View>
```